# VBA, If active cell in range does not equal a String call Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to the World of VBA. I am attempting to add to an existing Private Sub(Change). I am trying to "fire" the Macro "DelRCE" When the Active Cell in Range("K2:K700") Does Not equal the word "Down".

The code below is not working:

```
Dim txt As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim vec As String

txt = ActiveCell.Value
rng = ("K2:K700")
vec = "Down"

If r_ng.txt <> vec Then
    Call Macro
End If
```

Comment: What do you mean by Private Sub(Change)? Does that mean you have a Change Event code on Sheet Module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim key As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set the word you want to search for. Take capital letters into account
    key = "down"

    'Set worksheet to the first sheet in your workbook
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    'Change this to the range you want to search
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A100")

    'Check if the target is in the range
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> key Then
        'Change this to you function call
            MsgBox "The target is inside the range and the value is different from '" & key & "'"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes a Worksheet change. This works if the search word is in the range, and Loops through the entire range and Takes too long.  I need to identify if the LAST word entered into the range is the not the specified word and then call the Macro.

Comment: So on Worksheet_Change you want to check two things:
1. If the changed cell is in the specified range
2. If "Yes" to the first, then does it have a specific value
Is this understood correctly?

Comment: Thanks Noceo. Q1. = Yes, Q2. = Does not equal the value "Down"

Comment: Sorry the delay, had a busy weekend. I changed the code to fit what you describe. Note that is is caps sensitive. That can be fixed quite easily though, if needed.

Comment: No problem. Make sure to accept the answer, to make it easier for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor inside the test_Change sub and hit PF5 to run it.

```
private Sub Change()
Dim txt As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim vec As String
    txt = ActiveCell.Value
    rng = ("K2:K700")
    vec = "Down"

   If r_ng.txt <> vec Then
    Call DelRCE ' or "Run DelRCE" if it is a function
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub test_Change()
    call Change
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to the relevent Worksheet module, under the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim vec As String
vec = "Down"

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K700")) Is Nothing Then ' check that modifed cell is inside the Range("K2:K700")
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub ' Optional :  if more than 1 cell selected exut the sub

    If Not Target.Value Like vec Then ' Also possible to use: If Target.Value <> vec
        Call Macro
    End If
End If

End Sub
```